# handling Multiple buttons in $ionicPopup prompt

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

The documentation says:

> Show a simple prompt popup, which has an input, OK button, and Cancel
>   button. Resolves the promise with the value of the input if the user
>   presses OK, and with undefined if the user presses Cancel.

I was doing:

```
$ionicPopup.prompt({ 
  //options 
}).then(function (userinput) {
  //get userinput and send to server
});
```

I need to add a third button, but can't get the text of the input, how can I resolve the promise on the onTap event of the button to get the input?

```
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
   title: '¿Are you sure?',
   inputType: 'text',
   buttons: [
   { text: 'Cancel' 
     //close popup and do nothing
   },
   {
    text: 'NO',
    type: 'button-assertive',
    onTap: function(e) {  
      //send to server response NO
    }
   },
   {
    text: 'YES',
    type: 'button-energized',
    onTap: function(e) { 
      //get user input and send to server
    }
   }]
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps.

Comment: Thanks it helped me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this demo i made with your code: http://play.ionic.io/app/ac79490c8914
`prompt()` is not meant to add more than two buttons,`show()` is used to make complex pop ups, Please see `show()` method in same documentation. As written in documentation, i am quoting:

> Show a complex popup. This is the master show function
>   for all popups.
>
> A complex popup has a buttons array, with each button having a text
>   and type field, in addition to an onTap function.

Your code will be like:

```
$scope.showPop = function(){
    $scope.data = {};
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data.myData">',
    title: '¿Are you sure?',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
   { text: 'Cancel' 
     //close popup and do nothing
   },
   {
    text: 'NO',
    type: 'button-assertive',
    onTap: function(e) {  
      return null;
    }
   },
   {
    text: 'YES',
    type: 'button-energized',
    onTap: function(e) { 
      return $scope.data.myData;
    }
   }]
  });
  myPopup.then(function(userinput) {
    if(userinput){
      console.log('returned data'+ userinput)
    }
  });
}
```

Simple thing about above code is that you have bind input with `$scope` (`<input type="text" ng-model="data.myData">`) so you can access it in any manner.